# JS jQuery - check if value is in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

I am more of a PHP person, not JS - and I think my problem is more a syntax problem ..

I have a small jQuery to "validate" and check input value .

It works ok for single words, but I need array.

I am using the  `inArray()` of jQuery .

```
var ar = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]; // ETC...

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery("form#searchreport").submit(function() {
            if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first"), ar)){ 
                      //if (jQuery("input:first").val() == "value11") { // works for single words
            jQuery("#divResult").html("<span>VALUE FOUND</span>").show();
            jQuery("#contentresults").delay(800).show("slow");
                return false;
              }

        // SINGLE VALUE SPECIAL CASE / Value not allowed 
               if (jQuery("input:first").val() == "word10") {

                jQuery("#divResult").html("YOU CHEAT !").show();
                jQuery("#contentresults").delay(800).show("slow");

                return false;
              }

        // Value not Valid

              jQuery("#divResult").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);

              return false;
            });

        });
```

now - this `if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first"), ar))`  is not working right .. every value that I put will be validated as OK . (even empty)

I need to validate only values from the array (ar) .

I tried also `if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first"), ar) == 1) // 1,0,-1 tried all`

what am i doing wrong ?

Bonus question : how to do NOT in array in jQuery ?? 
(the equivalent of PHP `if (!in_array('1', $a))`  - I sw somehre that it will not work , and need to use something like this : `!!～`

Comment: `$.inArray(...) == -1` <----- there is no such element in an array

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are comparing a jQuery object (`jQuery('input:first')`) to strings (the elements of the array).
Change the code in order to compare the input's value (wich is a string) to the array elements:

```
if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first").val(), ar) != -1)
```

The `inArray` method returns `-1` if the element wasn't found in the array, so as your *bonus* answer to how to determine if an element is **not** in an array, use this :

```
if(jQuery.inArray(el,arr) == -1){
    // the element is not in the array
};
```

Comment: Your first `if` assumes that `-1` is treated as a falsy value? Shouldn't it be `!= -1`? +1 for the complete answer.

Comment: thanks, I was just modifying the code snippet and it must've slipped.

Comment: ok, thanks, it works great . but i have a clarification question - so there is no way to use the `inArray()` function without comparing it to `==` -1 , `== 0` or similar ??

Comment: no, bu if you really want to, you can make your own wrapper function :  `function notInArray(){return jQuery.inArray.apply(this,arguments)!=-1;}` which takess the same argumets as the initial function and returns a boolean (true if the element is not in the array);

Comment: thanks . it all works great . I am a real novice in JS . 90% of he time those are syntax errors :-) I am glad that now it wasn´t :-)

Answer (score 1):

As to your bonus question, try `if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first").val(), ar) < 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution of the values check

```
//Duplicate Title Entry 
    $.each(ar , function (i, val) {
        if ( jQuery("input:first").val()== val) alert('VALUE FOUND'+Valuecheck);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Array.prototype` property represents the prototype for the `Array` constructor and allows you to add new `properties` and `methods` to all `Array` objects. we can create a prototype for this purpose

```
Array.prototype.has_element = function(element) {
    return $.inArray( element, this) !== -1;
};
```

And then use it like this

```
var numbers= [1, 2, 3, 4];
numbers.has_element(3) => true
numbers.has_element(10) => false
```

See the Demo below

```js
Array.prototype.has_element = function(element) {
  return $.inArray(element, this) !== -1;
};



var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(numbers.has_element(3));
console.log(numbers.has_element(10));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```