# jQuery: how to check if a specific element is already in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the `var element` exists or not in the array `sites`?

```
var sites = array['test','about','try'];
var element = 'other';
```

Comment: `array('test','about','try');` ? Should it be `new Array(...)` or `[....]` ?

Comment: It's ***well worth*** your time reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It takes about an hour, two tops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` method like following.

```
if(sites.indexOf(element) > -1) {
    //exist
}
```

Comment: If IE8 support matters, that would need a polyfill or just use jQuery `$.inArray()` method

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**:

> Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

```
var sites = ['test','about','try'];
var element = 'other';
if($.inArray(element ,sites ) >= 0){
  //exists
}
```

Comment: it should be `>=` because item can be in 0 position in array.

Comment: @jcubic: thanks. missed `=` operator there

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first").val(), ar) != -1)
```

The inArray method returns -1 if the element wasn't found in the array, so as your bonus answer to how to determine if an element is not in an array, use this :

```
if(jQuery.inArray(el,arr) == -1){
    // the element is not in the array
};
```

Source :[JS jQuery - check if value is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491405/js-jquery-check-if-value-is-in-array)